# integrating Xero with bank API

Tags: java, xero-api

How do I integrate Xero with bank API? 
I have standard chartered bank API that I will like to integrate with Xero. I want to know if this is possible and also to know to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The Xero Bank Feeds API is a closed API that is only available to financial institutions that have an established financial services partnership with Xero. At this time there is no version of the API available for non financial institutions to use.

I'd recommend contacting Standard Chartered Bank to register your interest in them building a bank feed integration to Xero.